# Форма input hidden передает неверное значение

Tags: php

Написал такой код:

```
   <form action="soobchenie.php" method="post">

    <?php
    $soobchenie = $db->query("SELECT * FROM soobchenie WHERE dialog='$key'");

    foreach($soobchenie as $soobchenie2):
    $_SESSION['idp_msg']=$soobchenie2['idp_msg'];
    $idmsgn = $_SESSION['idp_msg'];
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="sendm" value="<?php echo $idmsgn; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="num1" value="<?php echo $idmsgn; ?>">

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <input id="sendmsgd" name="sendmsg" type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $msghhtadd[$th] ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="num2" value="<?php echo $mshtadd; ?>"><br>
```

Если нажать на кнопку submit с name="num1", то передается последнее значение из массива $soobchenie2['idp_msg'], по идею должен был передать то значение, на которое нажал. 
Пример:
Массив `$soobchenie2['idp_msg']` содержит такие числа:
`15`
`24`
`50`
`80`
Если нажму на кнопку с номером `24`, то на обработчик `soobchenie.php` передается `80`. С `15`, `24`, `50` аналогично. 
 В чем здесь может быть проблема?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name=???`

Comment: На вопросе забыл указать name, исправил. У меня он указан, передает всегда последнее значение.

Comment: будьте добры, покажите html страницы в браузере

Answer (score 1):

Вы в цикле выводите несколько элементов submit и несколько элементов hidden, в результате у вас получается форма вида

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="sendm" value="15">
<input type="submit" name="num1" value="15">
<input type="hidden" name="sendm" value="24">
<input type="submit" name="num1" value="24">
<input type="hidden" name="sendm" value="50">
<input type="submit" name="num1" value="50">
<input type="hidden" name="sendm" value="80">
<input type="submit" name="num1" value="80">
...
</form>
```

Форма передает то значение submit, которое вы нажали и пытается передать все значения скрытых полей, так как их названия их совпадают - они все уходят на сервер, где берется последнее значение. Вам следует переработать логику отправки данных. Если не будете менять значение value у кнопок - можно использовать их. Если в конечном примере значение в hidden будет отличаться от значения в кнопке, можно поместить его в data-атрибут кнопки и добавлять в форму или в запрос к PHP-обработчику средствами JavaScript.